# Can't see the change when i refresh my browser - Java EE web app. + Glassfish 4 + Netbeans + Java 7 + Mac os-

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I am working on web project using Java ee platform. If i make change on my files, i have always to run the project for seeing  changes in my web browser. If i only refresh my web browser the page remain the same without changes. So i can't create dynamic web application in theses conditions. Same problem happens using Eclipse IDE and other java and glass fish version. But using tomcat on Eclipse work fine. Have a problem also to configure properly tomcat in Netbeans.

Tools:
Mac osx 10.8.5*
Netbeans 7.4 *
Glassfish4 *
jdk-7u45-nb-7_4-macosx-x64 *
Browsers: safari, google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i uninstalled everything and installed netbeans 7.4 full pack with tomcat 70.4.1 at  https://netbeans.org/downloads/
everything work fine, but glassfish continues to taunt me :-(